# Error : sqoop to add records in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, sqoop2, sqoop

My scenario : I will get daily 100 records in hdfs through sqoop at particular time. But, yesterday i got only 50 records for that particular time today i need to get 50+100 records in hdfs through sqoop for that particular time. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so whats the error in that? your question doesn't state that....

Comment: how to add new records yesterday and today records in sqoop example

Answer (score 0):

To handle such scenario, you need to add a where condition on time. No matters, what the record count is.

You can use something like this in sqoop import command using --query parameter:

```
sqoop import \
  --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sqoop \
  --username sqoop \
  --password sqoop \
  --query 'SELECT * from records
                  WHERE recordTime BETWEEN ('<datetime>' AND NOW())  \
  --target-dir /user/hadoop/records
```

You need to modify the where condition as per your table schema.

Please refer [Sqoop Documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_selecting_the_data_to_import) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/your_mysql_databasename --username root -P --query 'SELECT * from records WHERE recordTime BETWEEN ('' AND NOW()) --target-dir /where you want to store data

and make when sqoop ask for password enter your mysql password eg.(my pwd is root)